# requests post from django to nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, django, post, python-requests

I trying to send data from django to nodejs. I receive but can't read data params.

Django:

```
response = {
        "status": "success",
        "voto":  all_votes,
        "user_choice": new_vote.value if new_vote else None
}    
import requests
requests.post('http://localhost:8081/vote_added', data = response)
```

NodeJS:

```
//router/index
router.post('/vote_added', votes.vote_added);

//votes controller
module.exports.vote_added = function(req, res) {
  console.log("test", req.params)
  console.log("test2", req.body)
  console.log("test3", req.query)
}
```

ps: my `response` is a dict

Comment: _ps: my response is a dict_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix that. Just change data to params in django request:

```
requests.post('http://localhost:8081/vote_added', data = response)
```

to

```
requests.post('http://localhost:8081/vote_added', params = response)
```

and in nodejs, work with `req.query`

Comment: `params = response` gets passed as query string and not as request body as you would expect in a `post` request. Use `json=response` and access req.body in Node (You would need `bodyParser` middleware).

Comment: I sending a dict, not json. But don't problem, I fix my problem, thanks.

Comment: I will still suggest use json :) and Python dict is equivalent to a JSON.